# Set a faker value less than another faker field

Tags: php, laravel, factory, faker

Hello I'm creating a Factory for a discount model. I have two fields ('original_price' and 'discounted_price'). I'm using randomFloat in factory to create a random number with 2 decimals for the 'original_price'. How can I set 'discounted_price' to be always a lower value than 'original_price'?

At the moment 'discounted_price' has the same faker value than 'original_price' because I cant find a way of doing this.

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\Discount>
 */
class DiscountFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'user_id' =>User::factory(),
            'category_id' => Category::factory(),
            'title' => $this->faker->sentence(),
            'slug' => $this->faker->slug(),
            'body' => '<p>' . implode('</p><p>', $this->faker->paragraphs(6)) . '</p>',
            'original_price' => $this->faker->randomFloat('2',0,2),
            'discounted_price' => $this->faker->randomFloat('2',0,2),
        ];
    }
}
```

I think I came across a solution but I dont know if this would be right. My idea is that the minimum value of 'discounted_price' should be 50% of 'original_price' and the maximum should be 'original_price' - 5. Would this be the correct way of doing it?

```
<?php

    namespace Database\Factories;

    use App\Models\Category;
    use App\Models\User;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

    /**
     * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\Discount>
     */
    class DiscountFactory extends Factory
    {
        /**
         * Define the model's default state.
         *
         * @return array<string, mixed>
         */
        public function definition()
        {
            return [
                'user_id' =>User::factory(),
                'category_id' => Category::factory(),
                'title' => $this->faker->sentence(),
                'slug' => $this->faker->slug(),
                'body' => '<p>' . implode('</p><p>', $this->faker->paragraphs(6)) . '</p>',
                $original_price = 'original_price' => $this->faker->randomFloat('2',0,2),
                'discounted_price' => $this->faker->numberBetween($min=$original_price/2, $max=$original_price-5)
            ];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems about right, I would advise you to not mix and match property assignment in the array values to keep things clear

```php
        public function definition()
        {
            $originalPrice = $this->faker->randomFloat('2', 0, 2);
            $discountMin = $originalPrice / 2;
            $discountMax = $originalPrice - 5;

            return [
                'user_id' =>User::factory(),
                'category_id' => Category::factory(),
                'title' => $this->faker->sentence(),
                'slug' => $this->faker->slug(),
                'body' => '<p>' . implode('</p><p>', $this->faker->paragraphs(6)) . '</p>',
                'original_price' => $originalPrice,
                'discounted_price' => $this->faker->numberBetween($discountMin, $discountMax)
            ];
        }
```